# Getting wrong year when tryting to convert unix seconds to a readable format

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs

I'm trying to convert a timestamp from a datetime input to a readable format. The timestamp is in unix seconds. When I try to convert the timestamp with momentJS, I get a completely different year (in this case 3990). How can I get the right year. The date is fully correct. I have some images below. First one is the value given on a converter website. Second image is console.log of the timestamp from the database, and last picture is what is displayed on the page.

```
{events.map((data) => {
                            console.log(data.date)
                            return (
                                <li key={data.key} className="event-card">
                                    <Link className="eventlink-card" to={{
                                        pathname: `/hendingar/${data.key}`,
                                        state: {passedData: data}
                                    }}>
                                            <h1 className="event-title">{data.name}</h1>
                                            <p className="event-date">{moment.unix(data.date).format('DD/MM/YYYY')}</p>
                                    </Link>
                                </li>
                            )
                        })}
```

[image: Website conversion]

[image: Log of timestamp value]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that console log output is from `console.log(data.date)`, then it looks like you're passing the entire object to `moment.unix` instead of just the seconds. Try `moment.unix(data.date.seconds).format('DD/MM/YYYY')`.

Answer (score -1):

try using

```
 moment.unix(1624876560).format('dddd, MMMM Do, YYYY h:mm:ss A')
```

it will output Monday, June 28th, 2021 1:36:00 PM (GMT+3 my timezone)

Comment: This doesn't answer why the OP is getting an unexpected date. He's not trying to change the format of the output.